# how to use bootstrap in react.js?

Tags: reactjs, npm, bootstrap-4

I downloaded bootstrap dependency under /node_modules/bootstrap using npm.

I added CDN link into index.html.

I cannot use some specific tags, I am not sure these tags are included into bootstrap or not.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

when i try to add some styles into my app, it turns exeption.

```
./src/App.js
  Line 16:  'Grid' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 17:  'Row' is not defined   react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 18:  'Col' is not defined   react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 21:  'Col' is not defined   react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 26:  'Row' is not defined   react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 27:  'Col' is not defined   react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 30:  'Col' is not defined   react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 33:  'Col' is not defined   react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 38:  'Row' is not defined   react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 39:  'Col' is not defined   react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 44:  'Row' is not defined   react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 45:  'Col' is not defined   react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 48:  'Col' is not defined   react/jsx-no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

here is my app.js file.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
render(){
    return (
        <Grid>
        <Row className="show-grid">
            <Col xs={12} md={8}>
                <code>&lt;{'Col xs={12} md={8}'} /&gt;</code>
            </Col>
            <Col xs={6} md={4}>
                <code>&lt;{'Col xs={6} md={4}'} /&gt;</code>
            </Col>
        </Row>

        <Row className="show-grid">
            <Col xs={6} md={4}>
                <code>&lt;{'Col xs={6} md={4}'} /&gt;</code>
            </Col>
            <Col xs={6} md={4}>
                <code>&lt;{'Col xs={6} md={4}'} /&gt;</code>
            </Col>
            <Col xsHidden md={4}>
                <code>&lt;{'Col xsHidden md={4}'} /&gt;</code>
            </Col>
        </Row>

        <Row className="show-grid">
            <Col xs={6} xsOffset={6}>
                <code>&lt;{'Col xs={6} xsOffset={6}'} /&gt;</code>
            </Col>
        </Row>

        <Row className="show-grid">
            <Col md={6} mdPush={6}>
                <code>&lt;{'Col md={6} mdPush={6}'} /&gt;</code>
            </Col>
            <Col md={6} mdPull={6}>
                <code>&lt;{'Col md={6} mdPull={6}'} /&gt;</code>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    </Grid>
)
}
}

export default App;
```

why grid, row and col are undef? how can i use all bootstrap features?

Comment: You can use ```react-bootstrap``` not  ```bootstrap```.

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction

Answer (score 4):

Looks like react can't find the elements from the react-bootstrap module.

---

If you haven't installed react-bootstrap, then use this command to install it.

```
npm install --save react react-dom
npm install --save react-bootstrap
```

And then import the required components to your page like below.

```
import { Grid, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

Answer (score 3):

Link your html page where you are rendering your DOM to the bootstrap file like

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/components/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

and you can use the bootstrap classes in every component which renders inside that DOM.

Answer (score 2):

In app.js or index.js import this line import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

import { Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed a package for bootstrap, you should probably import it in the page you need like

if you have installed a package named 'react-bootstrap', below will be the import statement for it

```
import * as BootstrapComponents from 'react-bootstrap'
```

You can import all using * or you can only take required components that you need from it like

```
import {Grid, Col }  from 'react-bootstrap'
```

Answer (score 1):

at first you need install bootstrap package this command:

```
npm install --save react-bootstrap bootstrap@3
```

Import Bootstrap CSS and optionally Bootstrap theme CSS in the beginning of your src/index.js file:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css';
```

if you need require react-bootstrap component so you need to import within src/App.js file :

```
import { Navbar, Jumbotron, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

after if you need use react-bootstrap package then need this command:

```
npm install --save react-bootstrap
```

when complete download then need to import this line src/index.js file.

```
import 'react-bootstrap/dist/react-bootstrap';
```

if you need grid and column just use your componen this link:

```
import { Grid, Row, Col, } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the javascript stuff done by the bootstrap library that modify the DOM is in conflict with the virtual DOM of React.

My advice is to use [reactstrap](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap) that supports bootstrap v4, or [React-Bootstrap](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap) that supports bootstrap v3. I tried both (started with React-Bootstrap since it is more popular) and liked reactstrap better.